# How to fetch Elixir dependencies per environment?

Tags: hex, elixir

There are multiple ways to install Elixir dependencies. I wonder what happens in the following cases:

#### 1.

```
mix deps.get --only prod
```

What exactly dependencies are being fetched then?

#### 2.

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:credo, "~> 0.8", only: ~w(dev)a, runtime: false},
  ]
end
```

How `only` option impact on a particular dependency?

#### 3.

```
def project do
  [
    # ...
    deps: deps(Mix.env()),
  ]
end
```

What is the difference if we specify dependencies like that?

---

I'm confused a little bit when to use what regarding defining dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to address these in reverse order.

using `deps(Mix.env)` would force you to specify each of your dependencies multiple times if they are used across multiple environments. Something along the lines of

```
def deps(:dev) do
  [
    {:ecto, "~> 2.1"}
    {:credo, "~> 0.8", runtime: false}
  ]
end
def deps(:test) do
  [
    {:ecto, "~> 2.1"}
  ]
end
```

I will admit that I do not even know if this would work, but this is adding too much code for something that is already handled for you if you just specify the `:only` option.

Using `:only` allows you to specify which environments a dependency should be used in. In your example, `{:credo, "~> 0.8", only: [:dev], runtime: false}` you are telling mix that the credo package should only be used in the dev environment. If you do not include the `:only` option, the package will be used in all environments.

`$ mix deps.get --only prod` will only retrieve the packages relevant to the production environment. From the previous example, the credo package will not be retrieved because you told mix that credo should only be used in the dev environment.

Comment: You defined `deps(:dev)` twice, I think you meant `deps(:prod)` for the second one ? Otherwise, I agree with you :)

Comment: I sure did. That's what I get for copy / paste to save a little time :(.

Comment: So what will happen for: `MIX_ENV=test mix deps.get --only prod`? Will `test` or `development` dependencies be fetched?

Comment: No, only `prod` dependencies.

Comment: Instead of swapping all dependencies per env you can swap just the particular dependency options: ```defp opts_for_pollution(env) when env in [:dev, :test], do: [path: "../pollution"]
  defp opts_for_pollution(_), do: []``` as @josevalim does here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/6345

Answer (score 5):

When you write this :

`mix deps.get --only prod`

It will fetch all dependencies for the prod environment, namely the dependencies where there is no `only` option, and dependencies where the `only` option is specified and containing `:prod` (e.g `{:some_dep, "~> 0.8", only: [:prod]}`)

When you write this :

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:some_dep, "~> 0.8"}
  ]
end
```

That tells mix to install `some_dep` in **any** environment it is run into.

When you write this :

```
defp deps do
  [
    {:another_dep, "~> 0.8", only: [:dev]}
  ]
end
```

It tells mix to install `another_dep` only when your environment is `dev` (`MIX_ENV=dev`).
If you are in any other environment (e.g. prod), `mix deps.get` will simply ignore `another_dep` and won't install it.

writing this :

```
def project do
  [
    # ...
    deps: deps(Mix.env()),
  ]
end
```

will result in `** (CompileError) mix.exs:13: undefined function deps/1` because in your `mix.exs`, only `deps/0` is defined. Now you might tell me why not implement `deps(:dev)`, `deps(:prod)` and so on... Well, if you read what I explained before, you'll see that it is pointless, since the deps separation for each environment is already taken care of :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Phoenix. Phoenix is a framework for building web applications in Elixir. Phoenix does not install anything.

Comment: Sorry, updating this, I was too into Phoenix these times ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I meant `mix`. The answer applies now though, don't you think ? :)